# Android - How to start service and activity on same time?

Tags: android, android-service, android-activity

I want to start service and activity on same time. I am using the following code, It is correct?

```
startService(new Intent(this, Service.class));
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But here after service is complted then only Activity starting. Why?
Please help anyone.

Comment: Yes.because your startActivity method is executes after startService() method.

Comment: So how to call service and activity on same time?

Comment: What is the return value from startService? That will tell you if the service has started. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29

Comment: @Paul No need any return value just calling service and activity.

Comment: Please read my comment again and follow the link to read the Javadoc. I am saying this is a way to determine if the service is started, not that you need a return value from the service itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to launch few threads and use semaphore with barier flag.

Comment: I have tried below code also it is not working. new Thread() { public void run() { try{ startService(new Intent(this, Service.class)); } catch (Exception e) { } } }.start(); Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class); startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to start an Activity and a Service that run in the same **process** (which is the default behaviour) at the same time.

The onCreate() method of the Service runs on the main (UI) thread.

The onCreate() method of the Activity also runs on the main (UI) thread.

The only way to have both start at more-or-less the same time is to have the Service run in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

After super.onCreate method, write:

```
startService(new Intent(this, Service.class));
setContentView("Your layout class name")
```