# Starting Activity With Intent Flags Stops Service After It Starts

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

In my app, there's an activity which leads to another through an intent with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherClass.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Service.class));
startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is the flags set on the intent makes it so that immediately after the `onStartCommand()` function is called in the service class, the `onDestroy()` function runs in the same service class. I need the flags set on the intent so that the user can't back into the MainActivity. Does anyone know how I can achieve this effect without having the service stop?

Comment: Is it possible to make the statement startService() be the first and then start another activity?\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10918036/1461078

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling finish() which, when used when starting intents, achieves the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the service in another process.

add this in the manifest

```
<service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":my_process" />
```

Comment: I added that but once I ran the application and the intent runs, my service doesn't start. I added a breakpoint at the onStartCommand() and it didn't hit it. Is there something else I have to do besides adding this change to my manifest?